# crosh>shell developer mode on chromebook

Tags: android, chromebook

I have a Samsung Chromebook OS and I'm in developer mode. I want to get android apps and linux on my laptop. I know how to get into the terminal it pulls up in a tab and I can enter the shell, but when installing crouton, I run into a problem resulting in the

> Error: sudo command unknown

It says unknown command every time I enter a command.
How do I make it read my commands, am I not opening the Terminal in the right way?

Answer (score 1):

Press and hold the following: Esc Refresh Power This will put your Chromebook into recovery mode a prompt window will pop up hit Enter, then Ctrl D, this will put you in Developer mode, after it loads it will beep press Ctrl D again and go through the set up prompts, when your set up press Ctrl Alt T to bring up Crosh now sudo commands will be recognized.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get android apps and linux on my laptop.

Okay. Here you go:

- [Install Android apps on your Chromebook](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/7021273?hl=en)
- [Set up Linux (Beta) on your Chromebook](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/9145439?hl=en)

> I have a Samsung Chromebook OS

There are many "Samsung Chromebooks" out there. Does it support Android and Linux apps? Is it really on the latest OS version? Then you should have access at least to Android apps, the Linux App feature is only supported on very few Samsung devices at the moment, see the list in the official help page. I have some Chromebooks, the latest being the C434 (shyvana) and everything worked by just following the the official instructions.

> and I'm in developer mode.

Sorry but no you are clearly not. But that's not the point, access to `sudo` will not improve your current situation if you just want to install Android or Linux apps.

> when installing crouton

Okay completely different topic. You have to follow the instructions for that.

https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton#Prerequisites

I'm not a fan of crouton because of the many users that showed up here with unsolvable "Linux/Ubuntu problems" that were related to Crouton and Chrome OS and were difficult to reproduce in other setups. Developers at Google however were impressed by the possibilities and developed [crostini](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/master/containers_and_vms.md) (Linux Apps on Chrome OS).

Be warned that:

- If your employer/school/organization provided this device for you to work then you may not be able to enter developer mode. If you bought a used device from ebay or so then you may have the same problem that the device has enterprise enrollment on it.
- Chrome OS updates may "Powerwash" your device from time to time. **This means you will loose all you data.** I did not believe it myself, but I just powered on my older N22, and yeah it tells me it's going to Powerwash once the update has been applied. No reason to worry if you use a Chromebook like a Chromebook where all the data is mirrored on Google servers. Big issue if you start using crouton or Linux (beta) feature.

Long story short: You need a Chrome OS device that supports Android and Linux apps. Developer mode not required.

Answer (score 0):

After bringing up the terminal you need to enter `shell` and Enter.  Now sudo should be recognized.

Answer (score 0):

You have to type the command "shell" into crosh for regular linux commands like sudo to work.

Answer (score 0):

Shell isn't working for me.  I get the following for all commands I enter:

`[ERROR:src/main.rs:184] ERROR: unknown command:` (command I entered)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1129380)